# Calculate average from data in array of object and store in specific key from object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have an array of object,

```
const book = [{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1231},{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1254}, 
              {'name':'beta','readingTime':190},
              {'name':'theta','readingTime':909},{'name':'theta','readingTime':10}]
```

I want to calculate average for each name, such that expected O/P is

```
**{alpha:1242.5, beta:190, theta:459.5}**
```

For this I tried as ,

```
let calculatedValue = book.reduce((acc,curr) => acc+curr.readingTime,0)/book.length
```

This gives me average for all the object.

I'm unable to form logic corresponding to it.

Any guidance would really be helpful. If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `name` and get the count and total of `readingTime` and build a new object with the averages.

```js
const
    books = [{ name: 'alpha', readingTime: 1231 }, {  name: 'alpha', readingTime: 1254 }, { name: 'beta', readingTime: 190 }, { name: 'theta', readingTime: 909 }, { name: 'theta', readingTime: 10 }],
    averages = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(books.reduce((r, { name, readingTime }) => {
            r[name] = r[name] || { count: 0, total: 0 };
            r[name].count++;
            r[name].total += readingTime;
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(([k, { count, total }]) => [k, total / count])
    );

console.log(averages);
```

Comment: Double question mark is giving me unexpected token, while using in vscode. What could be alternative for this

Comment: take a logical OR instead. please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another simple solution for you.

```js
const book = [{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1231},{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1254}, 
{'name':'beta','readingTime':190},
{'name':'theta','readingTime':909},
{'name':'theta','readingTime':10}]

const result = {};

Object.values(book.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current.name] = acc[current.name] || { count: 0, total: 0 };
    acc[current.name].total += current.readingTime;
    acc[current.name].count += 1;
    acc[current.name].name = current.name;

    return acc;
}, {})).forEach(({ name, count, total }) => { result[name] = total / count; });

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Need more optimization (Fell free to edit ) but it works

```js
const book = [{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1231},{'name':'alpha','readingTime':1254}, 
              {'name':'beta','readingTime':190},
              {'name':'theta','readingTime':909},{'name':'theta','readingTime':10}]


function avgReading(arr){
let alpha = { lengtharr : 0 ,readingAll : 0 };
let beta = {...alpha};
let theta = {...alpha};
arr.forEach((item) => {
  if(item.name === 'alpha') 
    alpha.lengtharr++;
    alpha.readingAll = alpha.readingAll + item.readingTime;
  if(item.name === 'beta') 
    beta.lengtharr++;
    beta.readingAll = beta.readingAll + item.readingTime;
 if(item.name === 'theta')
    theta.lengtharr++;
    theta.readingAll = theta.readingAll + item.readingTime;
});
const obj = {
'alpha' : alpha.readingAll /alpha.lengtharr,
'beta' : beta.readingAll /beta.lengtharr,
'theta' : theta.readingAll /theta.lengtharr
}
return obj;
}
console.log(avgReading(book))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tyy this

```
let obj = book.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    acc[curr['name']] = acc[curr['name']]?acc[curr['name']]:[0,0]
    acc[curr['name']][0]+=curr['readingTime'];
    acc[curr['name']][1]+=1;
    return acc;
}, {})

let calculatedValue ={};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>calculatedValue[key]=obj[key][0]/obj[key][1])
```

Comment: A switch case with always the same code, just different keys... You can program everything with a switch case but It's not maintainable..